# Error while using jdbc to MySQL connection | Naming Exception

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, jdbc, jndi

I'm a total beginner and i'm doing a simple jee project using Tomcat 9.0, MySQL and jdbc.
While trying to connect to the DB i get:
`javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/city2] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].`

I've already tried to add config file to Tomcat folder **apache-tomcat-9.0.24\conf\Catalina\localhost**, but it did nothing.
This is how my ConnectionProvider class looks like:;

```
    private static DataSource dataSource;

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return getDSInstance().getConnection();
    }

    private static DataSource getDSInstance() {
        if (dataSource == null) {
            try {
                Context initContext = new InitialContext();
                dataSource = (DataSource) initContext.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/city2");
            } catch (NamingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return dataSource;
    }
```

And my **context.xml** file looks like:

```
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/city2"
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              initialSize="10"
              maxTotal="100"
              maxIdle="30"
              maxWaitMillis="10000"
              username="root"
              password="admin"
              driverClassName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/city2?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC"  />
</Context>
```

[image: The intelliJ project structure]

[image: The db setup]

Comment: This is a JNDI error, and it has to do with your servlet configuration. Nothing to do with JDBC yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare datasource in web.xml:

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/city2</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

See more details [here](http://%20%20%20%20https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html).